# Two ways to load image, why is using ajax faster?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have two ways for loading a image, to test the loading speed.

First:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
var date1 = new Date().getTime();
img.src = "xxx.png";
img.onload = function() {
    var date2 = new Date().getTime();
    var delta = date2 - date1;
};
```

Second:

```
var date1 = new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({ url: "xxx.png",
         data: { _s: new Date().getTime(), },
         success: function () {
             var date2 = new Date().getTime();
             var delta = date2 - date1;
         }
       });
```

The above two ways I've tested many times. The second is 30% slower than the first, but I don't know why. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Ajax is slower for me. http://jsfiddle.net/f9zRT/

Comment: yeah, me too, but i just don't know why exactly.

Comment: Wait - @pimvdb says that the **second** way ("ajax") is slower, but your question says that it's faster.

Comment: @Pointy: That's what I'm experiencing on Chrome 15. Perhaps is because of the jQuery overhead - could you tell me what you're experiencing?

Comment: sorry, i just made a mistake. the first way is faster than the second(ajax).

Comment: With your fiddle, sometimes one is faster, sometimes the other. I'm running Firefox 7 on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

When you load the file *as an image*, the browser decodes the ".png" encoding to prepare the image for display. It doesn't call your "load" handler until it knows it's a good image.  In the second case, you're just fetching the data, so the browser doesn't care whether it's a valid ".png" file or not.

That's my bet, anyway. I'm pretty sure that if you loaded a random data file (not an image) the first way, your "load" handler would never be called.

*edit* Well the "mistake" in the original question makes the speculation behind this answer basically worthless.  (The original question read that the second — ajax — was **faster** than loading via a newly-constructed image.)

Comment: yes, it only called when the file is a image. but in your opinion, the second way is faster, it doesn't match my test result.

Comment: @piggy_Yu But you clearly state in the question, "the **second** is 30% **faster** than the first".

Comment: The thing is, when you're trying to time something that takes just a couple hundred milliseconds, there are many system effects that make a difference. You're just loading a "favicon" file; try the test with a multi-megabyte image.

Comment: yes, i test a 10M size image, and get the result. i think it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you compare a hard-coded browser function (*i.e.*, `img.src="xxx.png"` loading an image) to a complex JavaScript operation (*i.e.*, `$.ajax(almost anything)`), the JavaScript code is going to lose.  Interpreted scripting languages have a hard time matching the speed of the compiled code they're scripting.

Comment: Nowadays JavaScript is compiled in-time, so it's probably not an interpreter-related issue.

Comment: @Ross, i think both two ways need interpreted, and this is not the point.